# Output of a TRC query?

Tags: database, output, relational-database, predicate

Consider the relation employee(name, sex, supervisorName) with name as the key, supervisorName gives the name of the supervisor of the employee under consideration. What does the following Tuple Relational Calculus query produce?

[image]

1. Names of employees with a male supervisor.
2. Names of employees with no immediate male subordinates.
3. Names of employees with no immediate female subordinates.
4. Names of employees with a female supervisor.

---

My attempt :

inner query returns (note - without its negation) "Names of employees with a male supervisor" , but

inner query return (with its negation) = "other than Names of employees with a male supervisor"  in available relation , then it means ="Names of employees with a female supervisor."

Hence , option (4) is true .

---

Somewhere it explain as :

Query is selecting e such that e is an employee and for all x, either x is not an employee or x's supervisor's name is not e.name or x is male.

So, this is equivalent to saying, select all employees who don't have an immediate female subordinate. (Assuming there is no transgender). Option (3) is true.

> Can you explain in formal way, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separating the various part of the query:

Innest part (from the first OR to the end)
You're selecting all employees that are supervisor of someone (and not themselves) or are male.

From the "ALL X" to the end
You're selecting all the employees excluding those extracted from the previous subquery, so you're selecting all the employees that are supervisor of someone (but not themselves) and whose subordinates are male.

From the beginning to the end, you're selecting all the employees that don't have any female subordinates.

From the whole set of "employees" you're excluding those records, actually excluding all those employees have some female subordinates.

C is the right answer.